# Sharepoint Online Video Thumbnails auto generation not working in Asset Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, asset-library

We have a Asset library in Sharepoint Online site. The issue we are facing is when i upload a video to the asset library the preview image is not generating automatically.

I need to show the preview image without manually generating the thumbnail for videos.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot? There should be a Thumbnail view in the library.

Comment: Hi Nirikshita - did either of the Answers help to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, it is by designer that when we upload a video to the asset library the preview image is not generated in SharePoint online.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a look in a Video Library - I found an example of an item lacking the `Preview Image` - instead it just shows a folder icon.

[image]

When I checked in Windows Explorer I found there is no file inside the `Preview Image` folder.  Hence no thumbnail is displayed.  You can manually add your own image to create a thumbnail.

[image]

I found a [MS link on Video thumbnails](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/capture-or-change-a-video-thumbnail-bbf52fe0-3dd6-4bd7-b199-ccde413f6b1e) and also a [similar question posted here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/192df6df-fa20-43d5-a4c3-3ed8ff2a040a/video-libraries-on-sharepoint-online-with-video-content-type-thumbnails-not-appearing-in-libraries?forum=onlineservicessharepoint).  According to [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b4bf1aa-b10e-4282-a1dd-fb8c836ecd6d/sharepoint-2019-document-library-doesnt-show-thumbnail-or-image-preview?forum=SP2019) you need to use Classic View.  I'm not using SPO, I'm still on 2013, but hopefully something in this answer helps.